# What are the steps to get $X(t)$, when we know what $f(X,t)$ is equal to, when solving ODE's (example attached)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

> $$f(X,t)=\pmatrix {-y \\x}$$
>   Exact solution is  circle:
>   $$X(t)=\pmatrix {r \cos(t+k) \\ r\sin(t+k)}$$

$f(x,t)$ is known to be $\frac{d}{dt}(X(t))$.

I am also confused about the additional $r$ and $k$ given in the answer and how to get to the answer itself (I assume $r$ would be the radius?)

I have not solved ODE's with matrices and lack the terminology, so could not find any help on how to solve something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide to MathJax which will allow you to typeset equations and formulae :)

Comment: What do you know about ODE, have you experience with some even simpler examples? In $\ddot x+x=0$, if you replaced the second derivative with the second order divided difference quotient, could you then solve the resulting discrete linear difference equation?

Comment: Best case, I'd like to know the mathematical name of the given system: $\mathit{f(x,t) = A}$, when we want to solve for $\mathit{X(t)}$

Comment: If $f(t,x)=Ax$, then the ODE system is linear and the solution obtained via matrix exponential, $x(t)=\exp(tA)x(0)$. Now add that here $A^2=-I$, so it acts as complex unit.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write your DE in the form 
$$X'=AX$$
A is a $\pi/2$ rotation (counter clock wise):
$$X'=\pmatrix{0 & -1\\ 1&0}X$$
You can solve this system without  matrix algebra:
$$X'(t)=\pmatrix{x \\ y}'=\pmatrix{-y \\ x}$$
It's the same as:
$$
\begin{cases} x'=-y \\
y'=x
\end{cases}
$$
$$x'=-y$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$x''=-y'=-x \implies x''+x=0$$
The cgaracteristic polynomial is:
$$r^2+1=0 \implies r= \pm1$$
The solution is then :
$$\boxed {x(t)=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)}$$
Do the same for $y$
$$y=-x'$$
$$\boxed{y(t)=c_1\sin(t)-c_2\cos(t)}$$
You can rewrite these solutions in the form $A\cos(t+B)$ with trigonometric formulas of addition.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am new to differential equations and have some questions regarding your reply:
step 1) - all clear, from the other answer I read, that it is called a 'linear system', is that correct?
step 2) - all good
step 3) I understand the first line, but not the second. We just get rid of the second variables in the matrices because they are not computationally significant?
step 4) could you explain -y' = -x ?
step 5) characteristic polynomials are a fairly new thing to me, aren't they used to compute eigenvalues though? How is it computed here (from which matrix?)

Comment: Yes it's a linear system...@NewToMaths

Comment: also, in the equation I provided $X(t)$, there were also terms $r$ and $k$, so is the $r$ computed from the characteristic polynomial the same? From what I have seen, the variables from the characteristic polynomial were called $\lambda$. Moreover, what is $c1$ and $c2$ here then? And where/what is $k$? From the other answer, $k$ is defined as a constant from the integration of $ϕ'(t)=1$. Sorry for many possibly childish questions, but I have a lot to figure out here.

Comment: $y'=x$ is given from the matrix..you have $x'=-y$ too. Since $X=(x,y)$ and $X'=(-y,x)$

Comment: the k term is just a constant ..; it comes from the trigonometric formula for additon of two angles @NewToMaths  $c_1,c_2$ are just constants that you can choose. Or if you are given initial conditions you can fix the value of these constants; It's not the case here. They are equivalents to the $r,k$ constants in your answer formula

Comment: Thank you. Also, if $y′=x$ is given from the matrix, is the $y=x′$ a typo in your answer then?

Comment: Oh corrected it's a typo @NewToMaths I added also some lines for the equations deduced from the matrix

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the right side, you might recognize that it represents a rotation by $90^\circ$ of the position vector. Now one should know that the curves that go in a direction orthogonal to their direction vector all lie on circles around the origin. And indeed, you can calculate and insert
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)=0.
$$
Now set $r=\sqrt{x(0)^2+y(0)^2}$ so that 
$$
x(t)^2+y(t)^2=r^2
$$
This is a circle equation for the circle around the origin of radius $r$. Points on the circle can be parametrized by the trigonometric functions, that is, by their polar coordinates
$$
x(t)=r\cos(\phi(t)),~~ y(t)=r\sin(\phi(t)).
$$
Now computing derivatives one finds $\dot \phi(t)=1$, which has the general solution $\phi(t)=t+k$.